# Como cerrar modal y navbar al mismo tiempo

Tags: javascript, html, modal, navbar

Tengo un navbar ubicado en el pie de pagina de mi desarrollo el cual contiene un aviso para uso de cookies con dos botones, el primer botón **Aceptar** cierra el navbar y se crea una cookie y el segundo botón **Revisar** abre una ventana modal.

La ventana modal también contiene un botón **Aceptar** pero al momento de darle en este botón solo se cierra el modal. Quisiera que al dar click en el botón **Aceptar** de la ventana modal se cierre el modal junto con el navbar y pues que de igual modo como se cierra el navbar se cree la cookie.

El siguiente es el código de mi navbar:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="cookie_consent_user_accepted" class="alert alert-infoCookie alert-dismissible fade in navbar-fixed-bottom hide" role="alert" style="margin-bottom: -1px; font-family: Lettera Text Std;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>     
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                <h4>Titulo del aviso</h4>
                <p>Aquí va el contenido del aviso </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="display: grid;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-cookie" data-dismiss="alert">Aceptar</button>
                <br/>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-cookie" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Revisar</button>
            </div>
    </div>
```

El siguiente es el código de mi ventana modal que se abre al dar click en el botón **Revisar** de mi navbar:

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="font-family: Lettera Text Std; font-size: 12px;">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label"><strong>Ventana modal</strong></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  Aqui va el contenido de mi modal
                </div>
                <div id="cookie_consent_user_accepted" class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-cookie" data-dismiss="alert">Aceptar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Aquí mi codigo Javascript con el cual manejo el evento de cerrar el navbar y que se cree la cookie

```
if (!getCookie("cookie_consent_user_accepted")) {
    $("#cookie_consent_user_accepted").removeClass("hide")
}

// Hide if cookie is active
$("#cookie_consent_user_accepted").on("closed.bs.alert", function () {
    $("#cookie_consent_user_accepted").addClass("hide")
    setCookie("cookie_consent_user_accepted", true, 1)
    return false
});

// Create cookie
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date()
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString()
    } else var expires = ""
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/"
}

// Get cookie value
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "="
    var ca = document.cookie.split(";")
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i]
        while (c.charAt(0) == " ") c = c.substring(1, c.length)
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length)
    }
    return null
}

// Delete the cookie
function eraseCookie(name) {
    setCookie(name, "", -1)
}
```

**Actualización:**

Siguiendo alguna de las respuestas aquí estoy obteniendo el siguiente error en la consola del navegador al momento de dar click en **Aceptar** en la ventana modal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has tratado de añadir la clase ```hide``` a ambos elementos que quieres ocultar?

Comment: @christian Te refieres a la clase `hide` que contiene el `navbar` al comienzo del código ?

Comment: @christian Realice la prueba colocando la clase `hide` en el modal y ahora ya no se abre al seleccionar el boton Revisar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás asignando el ID `cookie_consent_user_accepted` tanto al *nav* como al pie de la ventana modal. Recuerda que los ID deben ser únicos:

> El atributo global id define un **identificador único (ID) el cual no debe repetirse** en todo el documento. Su propósito es identificar el elemento al vincularlo (usando un identificador de fragmento), en scripts u hojas de estilo (con CSS).
> Referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Para el pie de la ventana modal deja solo `<div class="modal-footer">`.

No sé si puedes agregar múltiples elementos en `data-dismiss`, pero puedes asignar un evento al botón para cerrar el *nav*, sin afectar el comportamiento normal de cerrar la ventana modal: `data-dismiss="modal"`.

SO no permite el uso de cookies en fragmentos de código, por lo que tuve que comentar algunas líneas para que pueda funcionar aquí.

```js
// En fragmento de código no se permite el uso de cookies
// let cookieAccepted = getCookie("cookie_consent_user_accepted");
// Por defecto, será falso. Elimina estas dos líneas y descomenta la anterior
let cookieAccepted = false;

if (cookieAccepted) {
    // Ocultar si ya se aceptaron condiciones y existe la cookie
    $("#cookie_consent_user_accepted").addClass('hide');
}

// Hide if cookie is active
$("#cookie_consent_user_accepted").on("closed.bs.alert", function () {
    $("#cookie_consent_user_accepted").addClass("hide");
    // Descomenta la siguiente línea
    // setCookie("cookie_consent_user_accepted", true, 1);
    return false
});

// Asignar evento al botón "Aceptar"
$('.modal-footer button').on('click', () => {
    $("#cookie_consent_user_accepted").addClass("hide");
    // Descomenta la siguiente línea para guardar la cookie
    // setCookie("cookie_consent_user_accepted", true, 1);
});

// Create cookie
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date()
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString()
    } else var expires = ""
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/"
}

// Get cookie value
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "="
    var ca = document.cookie.split(";")
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i]
        while (c.charAt(0) == " ") c = c.substring(1, c.length)
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length)
    }
    return null
}

// Delete the cookie
function eraseCookie(name) {
    setCookie(name, "", -1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="font-family: Lettera Text Std; font-size: 12px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label"><strong>Ventana modal</strong></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              Aqui va el contenido de mi modal
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-cookie" data-dismiss="modal">Aceptar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="cookie_consent_user_accepted" class="alert alert-infoCookie alert-dismissible fade in navbar-fixed-bottom" role="alert" style="margin-bottom: -1px; font-family: Lettera Text Std;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>     
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                <h4>Titulo del aviso</h4>
                <p>Aquí va el contenido del aviso </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="display: grid;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-cookie" data-dismiss="alert">Aceptar</button>
                <br/>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-cookie" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Revisar</button>
            </div>
    </div>
```

**Actualización:**

En tu código debes eliminar la línea que asigna `cookieAccepted`, dejando solo la que trata de leer la cookie, eliminando las `//` para que no sea comentario:

```
let cookieAccepted = getCookie("cookie_consent_user_accepted");
```

Elimina estas dos líneas:

```
// Por defecto, será falso. Elimina estas dos líneas y descomenta la anterior
let cookieAccepted = false;
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta pero al parecer no funciono, ahora ya no me muestra mi navbar cuando ingreso a la pagina, igual verifique si la cookie estaba creada y no lo esta

Comment: Tendrás algún error en la validación de si existe o no la cookie ?

Comment: Probablemente tienes todavía la clase `hide`. No realicé validaciones, solo usé tu código tal como lo tienes, comentando la parte de las cookies para que pueda funcionar el fragmento de código.

Comment: Modificaste algo en el html, para el modal como mencionas solo deje `<div class="modal-footer">` ?

Comment: Ya revise y tenia la clase `hide` en el navbar, disculpa

Comment: Probé nuevamente y ahora ya me muestra el navbar y la ventana modal pero al dar aceptar no se cierra el navbar y obtengo un mensaje de error en consola que actualizo en mi pregunta.

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, lee la última parte.